# Model doesn't move in touch direction

Tags: unity-game-engine

Code:

```cs
private Touch touch;
public float speed;
public Animator animator;
Vector3 point = new Vector3();
Vector3 targetPos;
  
   
void Start() 
{  
    targetPos = transform.position;
}

void Update()
{
    if (Input.touchCount > 0)
    {
        touch = Input.GetTouch(0);
        if (touch.phase == TouchPhase.Moved)
        {
            transform.position = new Vector3(transform.position.x + touch.deltaPosition.x * Time.deltaTime, transform.position.y, transform.position.z + touch.deltaPosition.y * Time.deltaTime);
             
            Plane plane = new Plane(Vector3.up,transform.position);
              
            Ray ray = Camera.main.ScreenPointToRay(touch.deltaPosition);
            float point = 0f;
           
            if (plane.Raycast(ray, out point)) targetPos = ray.GetPoint(point); 
            transform.LookAt(targetPos);
        }
    }
}
```

The problem is when I touch the screen the character looks in the touched direction, but when I move it forward (bottom of the screen to slightly above) it still looks towards the touch position. I want it so when it moves it faces the direction its going.

Comment: What about if you change `if(touch.phase == TouchPhase.Moved)` to `if (touch.phase != TouchPhase.Ended && touch.phase != TouchPhase.Canceled)`?

Answer (score 0):

```
 touch = Input.GetTouch(0);
        if(touch.phase == TouchPhase.Moved)
        {
            transform.position = new Vector3(transform.position.x + touch.deltaPosition.x * 
             Time.deltaTime,transform.position.y,
             transform.position.z + touch.deltaPosition.y * Time.deltaTime);
         
       transform.LookAt(transform.position + touch.deltaPosition);
    }
```

Comment: I don't understand?

Comment: well did you try? did it work? if not, what are the errors

Comment: I couldn't figure it out..so I ended up using a floating joystick..